# Product of Binomial coeficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, products, multinomial-coefficients

Suppose I have a set $\{n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_m\}$ such that $n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^m n_i$. Is there a way to simplify the expression

$$
\prod\limits_{i=1}^m {n \choose n_i}
$$

I feel like this might be related to multinomial coefficients but I am not sure.

Comment: you can simplify in terms of two multinomials: would that be ok for you?

Comment: Yes, how does one go about doing that?

Comment: Also try taking the natural log of the product to get a sum of $\ln$(binomial coefficient) which then simplify into sums as well.

Comment: By writting out the factorials you can verify it is the same as $\binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_m}\binom{mn-n}{n-n_1,\dots,n-n_m}\binom{mn}{n} / \frac{(mn)!}{n!^m}$, not sure it makes it any simpler though  because of the division (at least the terms are integers)

Comment: would be as already pointed by @Sil